# phpexcel - Percentage sign not being shown for negative values

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, spreadsheet

I am writing to excel sheet some percentage values with following code. The positive percent values work fine. I can see the % sign with them. The negative values do not show a percent sign. However, when I double click a cell to edit, it shows the percent sign. I want to show percent sign for negative values as well. Is this possible? Here is my code, that writes the value:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
  ->getStyle('A2')
  ->getNumberFormat()
  ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
  ->setCellValueExplicit('A2', -0.05, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC;);
```

Comment: Seems to work well enough: what Writer are you using?

Comment: @MarkBaker PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007

Comment: I used both the Excel5 and the Excel2007 Writers to test, and it worked as expected with both.... whatever the problem is, it isn't that.... are you using any kind of binder that might be overwriting the format?

Comment: No I am not using any binder. However, I have the following template, in which column J I am writing the negative percent value.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7SXYVkSq25acy1oTFRVaXRadzQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE` used only for positive numbers, because it is equivalent for format `0%`. Excel's custom cell format must defined as `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>`.

So, you must use custom format, like `0%;-0%`:

```
// ... other code
->setFormatCode('0%;-0%');
```

Comment: Ok i tried it but it didn't work. I am getting same result. Also to let you know, i am dividing value by 100 before saving it in excel so for e.g. 10 is saved as 0.10 ... excel shows it as 10%